# Getting "Error: reading EC2 AMIs: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation." while trying to get list of AMI-s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm getting the following error:

```
Plan: 14 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Error: reading EC2 AMIs: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
    status code: 403, request id: aeb56889-5181-4fd8-bb1f-456784e08bf2

  with data.aws_ami.ami_linux,
  on _environment-local.tf line 37, in data "aws_ami" "ami_linux":
  37: data "aws_ami" "ami_linux" {

Error: Terraform exited with code 1.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The code in question is:

```
data "aws_ami" "ami_linux" {
  most_recent = true
  name_regex  = "^amzn2-ami-hvm-2.*-x86_64-gp2"

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.202*"]
  }

  owners = ["amazon"]
}
```

I have the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "gha_describe_images" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.gaadmin.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.gha_describe_images.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "gha_describe_images" {
  name   = "${var.brand}-${var.name}-describe-images"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.gha_describe_images.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "gha_describe_images" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:DescribeImages",
    ]
    effect    = "Allow"
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:1234567890:*"
    ]
  }
}
```

What sort of permission does my role appear to be missing and how could I further debug this? It doesn't make sense to me, because I thought these were publicly available AMI-s...?

Comment: What permissions do you have currently in the role?

Comment: The data source aws_ami requires that the role used by terraform has the permission ec2:DescribeImages

Comment: @SamRoch08 : Would you mind illustrating how to add this?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here we are talking about the role/user **used by** Terraform.
When running Terraform, the local program needs to access the provider (AWS) API. This local program has to authenticate to AWS via credentials.

It can either use :

1. A default local AWS profile (~/.aws/credentials).
2. A local profile (~/.aws/credentials or ~/.aws/config) like "[my-profile]"
3. AccessKey/SecretKey defined in this code.

In your code you may have a block that looks like :

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = <region>
  /* OPTIONAL */
  profile = <local profile such as "my-profile">
  /* OPTIONAL */ 
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "<an extra role that "my-profile" will assume>"
  }
  /* OPTIONAL */
  access_key = "my-access-key" #Not recommended
  secret_key = "my-secret-key" #Not recommended
}
```

For your issue, you need to check the role or user configured above (if nothing is configured except the region, it means you are in configuration *1.* ). This role should be able to describe AMIs (*ec2:DescribeImages*)

Finally, I suggest no managing the Terraform role/user by Terraform itself.

I hope it's clear enough for you.